# Set HTML textbox value from Javascript function return value- (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

How do I set the text box value from javascript return value? I tried the below code it's not working- where am I wrong?

```js
function getname(name) {
  var subindex = name.indexOf(" ") + 1;
  return (name.substring(subindex));

}
var res = (getname("Harpreet Kaur"));
document.getElementById("lname").value = res;
//alert(res);
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="text" id="lname">
</body>
```

Comment: But, it's working as expected

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly:

```js
function getname(name) {
  var subindex = name.indexOf(" ") + 1;
  return (name.substring(subindex));

}
var res = getname("Harpreet Kaur");
document.getElementById("lname").value = res;
```

```html
<input type="text" id="lname">
```